# 415 status code from from simple graphql-http setup

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, graphql

I was scanning over the graphql docs to find express-graphql deprecated so I decided to implement the recommended graphql-html version:

this is my server.js:

```
import { createHandler } from "graphql-http/lib/use/express";
import { buildSchema } from "graphql";
import http from "http";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const PORT = 4000;

var schema = buildSchema(
  `
    type Query {
        hello: String
    }
    `
);

const root = {
  hello: () => {
    return "Hello, world!";
  },
};
const handler = createHandler({ schema, rootValue: root });

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url.startsWith("/graphql")) {
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      });
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (req.method === "POST") {
      handler(req, res);
    } else if (req.method === "GET") {
      const htmlContent = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Simple Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
      `;

      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.end(htmlContent);
    }
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404).end();
  }
});

server.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
```

and my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>GraphQL Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Simple GraphQL query using fetch
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=urf8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `
          query {
            hello
          }
        `,
        }),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log('GraphQL Response:', data))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, I'm getting a status code of 415 in my browser and I'm not sure why. I tried adding the charset=utf8 header but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your encoding `urf8` should be `UTF-8`, also since you're not serving html from your express app you will need to set access control headers.

Here's a fixed version of your code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>GraphQL Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Simple GraphQL query using fetch
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `
          query {
            hello
          }
        `,
        }),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log('GraphQL Response:', data))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
import { createHandler } from "graphql-http/lib/use/express";
import { buildSchema } from "graphql";
import http from "http";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const PORT = 4000;

const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

const root = {
  hello: () => {
    return "Hello, world!";
  },
};

const handler = createHandler({ schema, rootValue: root });

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url.startsWith("/graphql")) {
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      });
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (req.method === "POST") {
      // Set CORS headers for GraphQL POST requests
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

      handler(req, res);
    } else if (req.method === "GET") {
      const htmlContent = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Simple Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
      `;

      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.end(htmlContent);
    }
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404).end();
  }
});



server.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
```

Comment: tried all of the above, error persists

Comment: did you copy the code i just pasted ? how do you open index.html ?

Comment: I'm using google chrome, clicking on it, I have exactly what you wrote

Comment: did you copy the code as is (you need the cors headers too) ? i hate to say this but it works on my machine.

Comment: ok nvm, I had a typo when I added the server listen, sorry about that. it works now thanks!

Comment: i also added mode cors to the html's javascript.

Comment: it seems I was missing the cors method, I don't get how that resolves a 415 status code

Comment: And now I'm running it without the cors mode and it's also working, go figure